# Aws android authentication awsconfiguration.json CognitoIdentity PoolId

Tags: amazon-cognito, aws-amplify

I made the setting in the awsconfiguration.json file in the manual installation section on this page as below, but there is a problem with the connection. CredentialsProvider> CognitoIdentity> Default> I couldn't find where is PoolId. Do you think this file is correct?
[enter link description here](https://aws-amplify.github.io/docs/sdk/android/authentication)

```
{
    "IdentityManager": {
        "Default": {}
    },
    "CredentialsProvider": {
        "CognitoIdentity": {
            "Default": {
                "PoolId": "arn:aws:cognito-idp:eu-central-1:669975270978:userpool/eu-central-1_uvDuqbLun",
                "Region": "eu-central-1"
            }
        }
    },
    "CognitoUserPool": {
        "Default": {
            "PoolId": "eu-central-1_uvDuqbLun",
            "AppClientId": "oa21u1vqpiibgsufm3cjultmg",
            "AppClientSecret": "osoj88r3b17fu7fnrqc4253dnsa6htk8ljecdfci6gf3q57so6e",
            "Region": "eu-central-1"
        }
    }
}
```